# ArcGIS Pro multipatch polygon dissolve

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, multipatch

I'm currently getting an error message (Error 000366 - Invalid Geometry Type) when trying to dissolve a multipatch (3d) polygon - does anyone know if a dissolve of a multipatch polygon is possible?
I can't find any answers within the documentation on multipatch polygons.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the documentation states *somewhere* that `Geometry` manipulation is a 2D operation. You can check with Tech Support, but I expect that Error 000366 is a No.

Comment: Thanks @Vince, having followed up that seems to be the case

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Union 3D](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/union-3d.htm) with the group_field parameter.